# The number of FixedLocator locations (4), usually from a call to set_ticks, does not match the number of ticklabels (9)

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to plot multiple graphs onto one graph from text files and I keep getting this error and am not sure how to change my code to fix it. Any help would be appreciated heres what I am working with:

```
axesX=[]
for i in range(len(resultsA)):
    axesX.append(i)

axesXlab=[]
for i in range(step,maxNoise,step):
    axesXlab.append(i)
    
axesXlab=np.insert(axesXlab,0,0,axis=0)
axesXlab=np.round(axesXlab/dim*100) #patterns must be loaded

print()
print('\033[1m'+'Average performance')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6*1.2, 4*1.2))
ax.plot(resultsA,color='darkblue',linewidth=1.5,marker='s',label="0.1") # label can be modified
ax.plot(resultsB,color='blue',linewidth=1.5,marker='d',label="0.2") #add of line for a 3rd line
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05,1),loc="upper left",title='Slope')
ax.set_xlabel('Pixels Flipped (%)', fontsize = 13)
ax.set_xticks(axesX)
ax.set_xticklabels(axesXlab)
ax.set_ylabel('Performance (%)', fontsize = 13)
ax.set_ylim(-5, 105)
fig.savefig('AverageMonteCarlo_multiple.jpg')
plt.show()
```

Error points to line 27 --> ax.set_xticklabels(axesXlab)

Comment: Well, you need the same number of ticks in `ax.set_xticklabels(...)`  (the "texts") as in `ax.set_xticks(...)` (the positions).  You can either leave out some of the positions, or provide empty strings for some of the labels.